# Trying to update outdated Polymer tag wiki

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8256034

The above edit was made to remove outdated code based on Polymer version 0.5, which is no longer valid with the 1.0 release.  The rejections all cite either readability, accuracy, or accessibility, all three of which I believe I improved upon with my suggested edit.  In addition, none of the three users that rejected the edit seem to have any activity at all in the Polymer tag, and should have Skipped the review rather than Reject when they did not have the requisite domain knowledge to accurately assess the edit quality.  Currently the StackOverflow interface does not seem to let me revise or resubmit my edit, apart from rewriting it.

I will resubmit my edit as it was before, however I believe there are several improvements to this process which StackExchange could make:

1. I received no notifications that my suggested edit was rejected.
2. Users with no domain knowledge of the wiki subject should not be asked to review, or should receive better training or incentive opportunities to skip reviews they cannot assess accurately.
3. The StackExchange system should allow me to revise or resubmit my edit without rewriting it from scratch.  Alternatively, making the diff page linked above copy/paste friendly would suffice.

Comment: It looks pretty good to me.  Maybe they didn't notice that it was a wiki edit, I know there have been meta posts about that before.

Comment: Figures, the one time the community rejects a tag wiki edit, and it was a valid one.

Comment: Re-suggest it, and we'll approve.

Comment: Re-suggested the edit.

Comment: Here's the new one: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8283453

Comment: I don't know if it would help, but making the summary a bit more aggressive.  Maybe even mentioning this is a tag wiki edit in the description of the edit.  Had a similar edit been done to a post, rejecting it would be the right answer, no?